# Can't start the worker for Running celery with Flask

Tags: flask, celery, celery-task

I am following the example given in the following url to run celery with Flask:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/

I followed everything word by word. The only difference being, my make_celery function is created under the following hierarchy:

```
package1|
        |------CeleryObjCreator.py
        |
```

CeleryObjectCraetor.py has the make_celery function under CeleryObjectCreatorClass as follows:

```
from celery import Celery

class CeleryObjectHelper:
    def make_celery(self, app):
        celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
        celery.conf.update(app.config)
        TaskBase = celery.Task
        class ContextTask(TaskBase):
            abstract = True
            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                with app.app_context():
                    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        celery.Task = ContextTask
        return celery
```

Now, I am facing problems with starting the celery worker.
In the end of the article, it suggests to start the celery worker as follows:

```
$ celery -A your_application.celery worker
```

In my case, I am using <> for your_application string which doesn't work and it gives the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'package1.celery'

So I am not sure what should be the value of your_application string here to start the celery worker.

## EDIT

As suggested by Nour Chawich, i did try running the Flask app from the command line. my server does come up successfully.
Also, since app is a directory in my project structure where app.py is, in app.py code i replaced app = Flask(name) with flask_app = Flask(name) to separate out the variable names
But when i try to start the celery worker using command

```
celery -A app.celery -loglevel=info
```

it is not able to recognize the following imports that I have in my code

```
import app.myPackage as myPackage
```

it throws the following error

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

So I am really not sure what is going on here. any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need to use a class? you didn't define a celery variable in your code

Comment: Tip: don't think Java while coding in Python :)

Comment: I did that way also by not having a class. simply created a file called flask_celery.py and put all the make_celery code in it. Now the code that has the tasks etc let's say is in file name examply.py. So when I try to run the worker using $ celery -A example.celery worker loglevel=info, everything that uses app for example from from app.requests import request starts failing on app where app = Flask(__name__). This happens after I introduce the celery related stuff

Comment: Check this example https://repl.it/LQdn/2

Comment: My code is exactly the same. However, when i start the worker I fails to recognize app in all the imports that use app. Here app = Flask(__name__). And imports that fail are something like from app.classA import cls. It starts giving ImportError: No module named 'app' error

Comment: I assume you are in the root directory where you have app defined in a file called app.py. run celery worker by `celery -A app.celery worker` and also run the flask app the same way you run it usually `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`

Comment: that's absolutely correct except for the last part. I run my flask app using eclipse ide with pydev plugin. I just right click the app.py file and run it then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154726/discussion-between-nour-chawich-and-hary).

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this issue?